# Por que no me inicia el programa?

Tags: c#, hilos

Por que no me inicia el programa, el programa si me iniciaba pero estaba haciendo unas modificaciones en el segundo for para que no me generara esferas empalmadas y al intentar iniciar el programa ya no me inicio, borre lo que había hecho y lo volví a iniciar para ver si iniciaba pero no funciono

```
 Graphics g;
    Thread hilo;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        hilo = new Thread(Dibujar);
        hilo.Start();
        
    }
    public void Dibujar()
    {
        Random rdn = new Random();
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        int down = 0;

        int[] ellipses = new int[20];

        for (int iteraciones = 0; iteraciones < 10; iteraciones++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                ellipses[i] = rdn.Next(this.Height);
            }

            while (down<this.Height)
            {
                g.Clear(Color.White);
                for (int ellipses1 = 0; ellipses1 <ellipses.Length ; ellipses1++)
                {
                    g.DrawEllipse(pen, ellipses[ellipses1], down, 10, 10);
                }
                down += 30;
                Thread.Sleep(120);
            }
            down = 0;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        hilo.Abort();
    }
```

Me marca
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tu programa ya esta corriendo y de alguna forma quedo trabado... proba reiniciar tu ide.. o fijarte si no esta corriendo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como le has dado varias veces, el programa está ejecutando. Tienes ue entrar al administrador de tareas y cerrarlo.
creo que mira el nombre en el bin/debug.
reinicia el ide es otrar opción XD

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).